# Dynamic Pageflip 3.5 - help needed changing a page

Tags: xml, flash

I have purchased a dynamic pageflip script from http://pageflip.hu/.

Has anyone used it before? I have setup all the pages and all is well, however, I am having trouble changing the very first left hand page. (see image -http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/3350/pageflip.jpg).

I have looked in both the .fla files and pagedate35.xml for an instance but  had no look.

Can someone who has used the script point me in the direction, all I want to do is replace the page with my own instructions as an image.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have never used the pageflip engine from pageflip.hu I am familiar with other very similar implementations (mainly [Megazine](http://megazine.mightypirates.de/)) and I think that part is not "the first left hand page", it is **outside** the book so it must be just some textfieds on the stage. Look in the .fla files on the **main timeline** and remove them  (or replace them with whatever you need).